# IntelliJ Idea doesn't reformat jspx file when it is "long"

Tags: intellij-idea

I found a strange behavior in Intellij Idea. In a complex jspx page with about 300 lines, intellij idea can no longer format the code properly.

**EDIT:** This problem only appears when the page is saved as .jspx. If I save it as .xml, the problem disappears.

For example this page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mycomponents"
    >
<ui:composition>
<f:view>
<p:panel header="XXX">
<p:outputLabel value="YYY"/>
</p:panel>
</f:view>
</ui:composition>
</jsp:root>
```

When I hit Ctrl+Alt+L, I get proper output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mycomponents"
    >

<ui:composition>
    <f:view>
        <p:panel header="XXX">
            <p:outputLabel value="YYY"/>
        </p:panel>
    </f:view>
</ui:composition>
</jsp:root>
```

But when I paste the `<p:outputLabel value="YYY"/>` in the page about 300 times, the autoformatting stops working.

In more complex examples, only part of the code is formatted(for example everything inside the `p:panel` is formatted, but `ui:composition` and `f:view` stays at the same position(no indent).

I didn't find any configuration in idea which would help. Is there a way to get rid off this behavior?

I use Intellij Idea 12 Ultimate

Comment: I just tried with around 2500 `<p:outputLabel value="YYY"/>` and had no issues in Intellij Idea 13. Any errors in the IntelliJ Idea log ? ("C:\Users\$user\.IntelliJIdea12\system\log\idea.log")

Comment: I think the formatting itself is ok. When I take a long formatted XML and press Ctrl+Alt+F, the indents disappear. 
The example of file I'm not able to format is here: http://pastebin.com/zyr9EvmC

Comment: Seems like a bug.  Same behavoir for me in IntelliJ 12.1.4

Comment: Ashutosh Jindal: It seems the problem only appears when the file is saved as .jspx

Comment: Yup the file I tried was .jspx. Perhaps it's been fixed in IntelliJ 13 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The workaround for the bug is to set `Code Style` | `HTML` | `Other` | `Do not indent children if tag size more than` **200** `lines`

The bug can be [tracked here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2323).

<s>It appears to be a bug, [reported here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113688), please vote.</s>

Comment: I like how you always find my SO questions. Great support for best IDE :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting for this behavior in idea:

Please adjust setting in: CodeStyle | HTML | Other | Do not indent children if tag size more than <200> lines

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113688

Comment: This setting is just a workaround, it's [still a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2323).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I misunderstood the conversation in jetbrains bugtracking.